# solid angle subtended by an infinitely long circular cylinder?

Tags: geometry

[image: Infinitely long circular cylinder]

An infinitely long cylindrical pole, with a diameter $D$, is standing on a plane surface. How to find out the solid angle subtended by the pole at any arbitrary point say P lying on the same plane surface at a distance $x$ from the center O of the base of the pole? (as shown in the diagram above) Is there any analytic formula to calculate the solid angle in terms of $D$ & $x$?

Note: $D$ & $x$ are finite values.

Comment: If you look at the rays from $P$ tangent to the sides of the cylinder, you will notice they lie on two planes. This mean if you project the cylinder onto a unit sphere centered at $P$,  the result will be a geodesic triangle and the angles at two of the corners are $90^\circ$ You just need to figure out what the third angle is...

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be measured upwards from zero in the plane shown.  If $x$ is large, we can consider the blockage by a rectangle $D \times dy$ at a vertical position $y$.  The distance is $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$, so the rectangle blocks a solid angle $d\Omega=\frac {D\ dy}{x^2+y^2}$  The total solid angle is then $\int_0^\infty \frac {D\ dy}{x^2+y^2}$

If $x$ is not so large you need to find the length of the arc of the circle of radius $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ that intersects the cylinder.  That will replace $D$ in the integral.  You are allowing for the fact that the two tangent lines do not touch the cylinder at diametrically opposite points.

Answer (score 0):

From the point P the cylinder looks like an infinite rectangular plate
of width $D$ and length $l\to \infty$ at distance $x$. Using the obvious mirror
symmetry, chopping the cylinder in half and multiplying the solid angle
by 2, the solid angle of the
finite rectangular plate is given by the text-book formula
$$
\Omega = 2\arcsin \frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{(1+\alpha^2)(1+\beta^2)}} 
= 2\arcsin \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{(1+\alpha^2)(1/\beta^2+1)}} 
$$
where $\alpha=D/(2x)$, $\beta=l/x$.
The appropriate limit is $l\to \infty$, $1/\beta\to 0$, so
$$
\Omega =2\arcsin \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{(1+\alpha^2)(1+\frac{1}{\beta^2})}} 
\to 2\arcsin \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}} .
$$